# multi insert row & table codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

i have 1 form new customer, which will insert into 2 table('tbcust' & 'tbcp'). I add button 'add new contact person' for insert row in table 'tcp', the button save in form will insert multiple table. table 'tbcust' is ok, but row 'nama_pt' in table 'tbcp' just passing 1 character.

CONTROLLER

```php
public function post_multiple_table(){

        $this->load->model('Multiple_model', 'multi_model', TRUE);
        $cust_input_data = array();
        //$cp_input_data = array();

        $cust_input_data['nama_pt'] = $this->input->post('nama_pt');
        $cust_input_data['tipe'] = $this->input->post('tipe');
        $cust_input_data['alamat'] = $this->input->post('alamat');
        $cust_input_data['email_cust'] = $this->input->post('email_cust');
        $cust_input_data['notelp'] = $this->input->post('notelp');
        $cust_input_data['nofax'] = $this->input->post('nofax');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_orang[]', 'nama_orang', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_pt', 'nama_orang', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nohp[]', 'nohp', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email[]', 'email', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
         echo validation_errors(); // tampilkan apabila ada error
        }else{

        $nm = $this->input->post('nama_orang');
        $result = array();
        foreach($nm AS $key => $val){
        $result[] = array(
        "nama_orang"  => $_POST['nama_orang'][$key],
        "nama_pt"  => $_POST['nama_pt'][$key],
        "nohp"  => $_POST['nohp'][$key],
        "email"  => $_POST['email'][$key]
         );
        }
```

model

```php
public function create_multiple_tabel($nama_pt, $nama_orang){
        $this->db->insert('tbcust', $nama_pt);
        $this->db->insert_batch('tbcp', $nama_orang);
    }
```

and this the form & database
[image: tbcp] [image: tbcust] [image: form new customer]

Comment: check your tbcp table and what is your type on nama_pt

Comment: on table tbcp, 'nama_pt' is varchar

Answer (score 0):

Check in table `tbcp` if your row `nama_pt` have length set `1`, and put `15` or higher if need.